# When the screen is touched, how do I make the game over?

Tags: ios, animation, swift, touch, sprite-kit

I want a game over screen and the game to stop when the screen is touched during a specific animation.

```
    let lightTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "green light.png")
    let lightTexture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "red light.png")

    let animateGreenLight = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0, withRange: 0.1),   SKAction.animateWithTextures([lightTexture, lightTexture2], timePerFrame: 3)])
    let changeGreenLight = SKAction.repeatActionForever(animateGreenLight)


    let animateRedLight = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0, withRange: 0.1), SKAction.animateWithTextures([lightTexture, lightTexture2], timePerFrame: 3)])
    let changeRedLight = SKAction.repeatActionForever(animateRedLight)


    let greenLight = SKSpriteNode(texture: lightTexture)
    greenLight.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 650)
    greenLight.runAction(changeGreenLight)

    self.addChild(greenLight)

    let redLight = SKSpriteNode(texture: lightTexture2)
    redLight.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 650)
    redLight.runAction(changeRedLight)

    self.addChild(redLight)
```

When the animation for the red light is on the screen, I want it to be game over.  Do I have to make an if statement, and if so for what specifically?

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make yourself another node which has the same size and position as the red light. Additionally, that node is able to handle touch events. Then, add that node before the animation runs. This can be done with a sequence of actions, e.g.:

```
let addAction = SKAction.runBlock({ self.addChild(touchNode) })
let animationAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(animateRedLight)

redLight.runAction(SKAction.sequence([ addAction, animationAction ]))
```

**Update**

Since you want the game to end when you touch anywhere, alter the code such that the block sets a variable which indicates that the animation is executed and implement `touchesBegan` which checks for that variable, e.g.

```
let addAction = SKAction.runBlock({ self.redLightAnimationRuns = true })

[...]

// In touchesBegan
if touched
{
    if redLightAnimationRuns
    {
        endGame()
    }
}
```

Comment: var touchNode = SKSpriteNode()                               touchNode.size = redLight.size
        touchNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 650)
        let addAction = SKAction.runBlock({ self.addChild(self.touchNode) })
        let animationAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(animateRedLight)
        redLight.runAction(SKAction.sequence([ addAction, animationAction ]))                          

This is what I added, when I write self.addChild(touchNode) the app crashes.  also, I dont think the animation for the touchNode is running.

Comment: How do I make it so that when the screen is touched anywhere, the game is over.

Comment: if touched gives an error.  touched is an unresolved identifier.  Also, "redLightAnimationRuns" is not in my game scene, were you referring to redLight my SKSpritenode?

Comment: Of course you have to redirect the selector to the correct instance. So if it is in the child, call the selector on the child. But this is something I cannot be aware of...

Comment: "if touched" gives an error, maybe its a typo.  What is the correct line of code?

Comment: This is not real code, you have of course get the touch inside `touchesBegan`.

Comment: so should it be 
override func if touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

Comment: Yes and inside that function you can use `touches.anyObject() as UITouch?` to get one of the touches.

Answer (score 0):

use the touchesBegan() function to call a GameOver() function when the red light is on the screen (which you can control with a variable).

So, when the red light comes on to the screen, variable redLightCurrent is set to true. in TouchesBegan(), when redLightCurrent is true, then call the gameOver() function where you can include what to do when the game is over. This will only occur when a touch has began on the screen.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

  super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
  let array = Array(touches)
  let touch = array[0] as UITouch
  let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

  if redLightCurrent {
       gameOver()
     }
  }
```

This code works with the new xCode 7 and Swift 2.0